# regex link with php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i am trying to regex a difficult link

```
preg_match_all('/<a[^>]*href\s*=\s*(["\'])(.*?)\1[^>]*>\s+TEXTTOFIND+(.*?)\s*<\/a>/', '<a href="http://subdomain.BLABLABLA.net/de/cgi/g.fcgi/BLABLABLA/print?folder=inbox&amp;uid=U3RlcClzESBNZK9SDGsmQ05yIJTj7Eax&amp;CUSTOMERNO=124332225&amp;t=de1142311604.1315866430.20ba8551" style="margin-right: 10px;" title="&quot;BLABLABLA.net Registrierung&quot; &lt;register@gutefrage.net&gt;">"TEXTTOFIND.net R...
            </a>', $match);
        print_r($match);
```

BLABLABLA is only a test to hide the real page :)

all I want is to find the URL of link with "TEXTTOFIND"

but it doesn't work :(

Comment: I love regex, but it's not suitable for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a DOM parser to do this, not regular expressions.  But if you want to do it the wrong way anyway, it looks like one of the reasons it isn't working is that you're trying to match:

```
... [^>]*>\s+TEXTTOFIND ...
```

But your test string is:

```
... >"TEXTTOFIND
```

Note the double quote `"` between the right angle bracket and your TEXTTOFIND string.  The modifier from your regex, `\s+`, will not match this.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

at first, try read docs, you miss 2nd parameter

at second, hello Alex :)

at 3rd \s+ you can change to . at some ... happens(sorry for my english)